# Jenkins stuck at sh command

Tags: flutter, jenkins

Here is my script while adding as a pipeline request

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Version check') {
          steps {
              sh "flutter --version"
            }
        }
    }
           
}
```

Here is the jenkins console

```
Started by user Akshay Gupta
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FirstPipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Version check)
[Pipeline] sh
```

**Edit 2**
After using **sudo ufw allow 8080** command on my terminal and changed the pipeline code the error remains the same is there anything i can do

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Version check') {
          steps {
              sh "flutter --version --no-version-check"
            }
        }
    }
           
}


[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FirstPipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Version check)
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FirstPipeline@tmp/durable-7c931453
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Edit 3**

So here i have solved the problem via removing the path variable from configure system file and it's executing the shell scripts but now my pipeline scripts look like this

```
pipeline {
    agent any
 environment {
        flutter = "/home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter/bin/flutter"
    }
    stages {
        stage('GIT PULL') {
          steps {
               git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/AkshayStackSum/demo_flutter_app_to_jenkins.git'

            }
            
      
        }
        
 
           stage('CLEAN') {
     steps {
                sh "${flutter} clean"
            }
            }
            
           stage('PUB GET') {
     steps {
                sh "${flutter} pub get"
            }
            }
    
    }
}
```

And my error look like this

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyPipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (GIT PULL)
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyPipeline/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/AkshayStackSum/demo_flutter_app_to_jenkins.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/AkshayStackSum/demo_flutter_app_to_jenkins.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/AkshayStackSum/demo_flutter_app_to_jenkins.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3076ef00fb2b7330735759edc957f471a8712117 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 3076ef00fb2b7330735759edc957f471a8712117 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D main # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b main 3076ef00fb2b7330735759edc957f471a8712117 # timeout=10
Commit message: "flutter project initiated"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 3076ef00fb2b7330735759edc957f471a8712117 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (CLEAN)
[Pipeline] sh
+ /home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter/bin/flutter clean
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter
rm: cannot remove '/home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter/version': Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (PUB GET)
Stage "PUB GET" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Edit 4**
So after many tries i am succeed in one git project but now i am using another repo and it's showing this kind of error it's working fine in local and launching app without any conflict but it's throwing this error i just change the git hub repo in my previous groovy script. git pull and flutter clean working charm in jenkins but when i try to pub get it throws this error

```
n":"2.1.3","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.61 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":">=0.12.5 <0.13.0","meta":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0","test":">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/2.1.3.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"16169b1cc79f01d9c47fe05b5670b87cbf7f5cfc77757369f245c36a6ae2b290","published":"2020-02-28T22:37:37.337683Z"},{"version":"2.1.4","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"2.1.4","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.61 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":">=0.12.5 <0.13.0","meta":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0","test":">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/2.1.4.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"5aebd0ad81fc83c6be79d93ceaa3371d60c1eac06dd34b07c0d06974032edfb3","published":"2020-10-26T21:34:46.463591Z"},{"version":"2.1.4+1","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"2.1.4+1","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.61 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":">=0.12.5 <0.13.0","meta":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0","test":">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/2.1.4%2B1.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"be9c6c979a6bf7b8deb3437f3119b13588ff36ce4ff59492b7773e12bdc6bc70","published":"2020-10-26T21:49:20.979008Z"},{"version":"2.1.5","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"2.1.5","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.61 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":">=0.12.5 <0.13.0","meta":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":">=1.0.0 <2.0.0","test":">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/2.1.5.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"e83f7ad1e6375da1400b54eea8793bba804d1731d68c5694490bf9296cd3ca24","published":"2020-11-06T00:38:09.398682Z"},{"version":"3.0.0-nullsafety","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.0-nullsafety","environment":{"sdk":">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10-nullsafety","meta":"^1.3.0-nullsafety"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0-nullsafety","test":"^1.16.0-nullsafety"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.0-nullsafety.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"467a81931eae537f7ed06d836204b5f2541d4cdd804f30e5def9ebf5930c11eb","published":"2020-11-06T01:14:42.006624Z"},{"version":"3.0.0-nullsafety.1","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.0-nullsafety.1","environment":{"sdk":">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10-nullsafety","meta":"^1.3.0-nullsafety"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0-nullsafety","test":"^1.16.0-nullsafety"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.0-nullsafety.1.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"430e3eb6e642a790b304a90fb1444330466de9228192729c60739fd30ca96039","published":"2020-11-06T01:32:45.901741Z"},{"version":"3.0.0-nullsafety.2","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.0-nullsafety.2","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10-nullsafety.3","meta":"^1.3.0-nullsafety.6"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0-nullsafety.3","test":"^1.16.0-nullsafety.8"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.0-nullsafety.2.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"48c610a3ade7bda69efaa5de716943d9902d7571ebb10f4a9c4e0896d25a98b5","published":"2020-11-06T02:09:57.515226Z"},{"version":"3.0.0-nullsafety.3","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","homepage":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.0-nullsafety.3","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10-nullsafety.3"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0-nullsafety.3","test":"^1.16.0-nullsafety.8"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.0-nullsafety.3.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"c30db7270f24a0135d4ae116c41b459e6269922691d810fe21461b495568d2cf","published":"2021-01-15T19:41:37.921126Z"},{"version":"3.0.0","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","repository":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0","test":"^1.16.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.0.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"ca3ae1a9b6c2a7712f6818c8ce6bbcc6cf999115f4fb51b1fa8b7bfe1037d70e","published":"2021-02-17T18:37:19.196841Z"},{"version":"3.0.1","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","repository":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.1","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0","test":"^1.16.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.1.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"5e592c348a6c528fb8deb7cc7d85a7097ce65bf2349121ad004d1fc5d5905eaa","published":"2021-04-06T16:37:06.849276Z"},{"version":"3.0.1+1","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","repository":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.0.1+1","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0","test":"^1.16.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.0.1%2B1.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"616b691d1c8f5c53b7b39ce3542f6a25308d7900bf689d0210e72a644a10387e","published":"2021-10-15T05:01:19.034255Z"},{"version":"3.1.0","pubspec":{"name":"quiver","description":"Quiver is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient, or adds additional functionality.","repository":"https://github.com/google/quiver-dart","version":"3.1.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dependencies":{"matcher":"^0.12.10"},"dev_dependencies":{"path":"^1.8.0","test":"^1.16.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver/versions/3.1.0.tar.gz","archive_sha256":"93982981971e812c94d4a6fa3a57b89f9ec12b38b6380cd3c1370c3b01e4580e","published":"2022-05-03T20:32:16.263955Z"}],"_fetchedAt":"2022-09-05T11:11:10.482766"}
SLVR:       fact: no versions of google_sign_in match >5.4.1 <6.0.0
SLVR:       conflict: no versions of google_sign_in match >5.4.1 <6.0.0
SLVR:   derived: not google_sign_in >5.4.1 <6.0.0
SLVR:   conflict: google_sign_in 5.4.1 requires Flutter SDK version >=2.8.0
SLVR:   ! google_sign_in 5.4.1 is partially satisfied by not google_sign_in >5.4.1 <6.0.0
SLVR:   ! which is caused by "no versions of google_sign_in match >5.4.1 <6.0.0"
SLVR:   ! thus: google_sign_in ^5.4.1 is forbidden
SLVR:   ! google_sign_in ^5.4.1 is satisfied by google_sign_in ^5.4.1
SLVR:   ! which is caused by "flutter_boiler_plate depends on google_sign_in ^5.4.1"
SLVR:   ! thus: version solving failed
SLVR: Version solving took 0:00:01.065682 seconds.
    | Tried 1 solutions.
FINE: Resolving dependencies finished (1.1s).
ERR : The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.
    | 
    | Because google_sign_in 5.4.1 requires Flutter SDK version >=2.8.0 and no versions of google_sign_in match >5.4.1 <6.0.0, google_sign_in ^5.4.1 is forbidden.
    | So, because flutter_boiler_plate depends on google_sign_in ^5.4.1, version solving failed.
FINE: Exception type: SolveFailure
FINE: package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 311:5               VersionSolver._resolveConflict
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 132:27              VersionSolver._propagate
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 96:11               VersionSolver.solve.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                     Future.catchError
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:52                              captureErrors.wrappedCallback
    | package:stack_trace                                            Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                              captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command.dart 189:13                            PubCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 176:24                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 161:20                     PubCommandRunner.run
    | package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 45:56                             runDartdev
    | /b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart 11:9  main
---- End log transcript ----
pub get failed (1; ---- End log transcript ----)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think `flutter --version` does an HTTP call to determine whether there are updates available. So this must be taking time, or maybe the request is blocked by your Firewall?

Try executing the below instead.

```
flutter --version --no-version-check
```

Comment: I have no idea if that will actually solve the problem, but it's a really good thought, so I upvoted anyway.

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
+ /home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter/bin/flutter clean
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter
rm: cannot remove '/home/stack/Desktop/developer/flutter/version': Permission denied
```

This part in your exception from edit3 is actually a *part* of the answer.
Your Jenkins instance does not have permissions to remove files or directories in that folder.

You could try to change the folder ownership with the command:
`sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /pathto/folder`

Comment: yes i have added a permission and it's working but now if i am trying new repo it's throwing the error as i i have mentioned in edit 4